# Passing arrays in to the function in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, array

I am new to a bash script and writing the bash script. I have declared an array and I have given the values. But When I pass the array in the loop values are not getting inside the loop. Below is my code

```
declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0" )
command_to_get_filesizes() {
  for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
     echo Processing file "${i[${index}]}"
  done
}
command_to_get_filesizes
```

**Expected Output**

```
A1S0
D1s0
D2S0
D3S0
D5S0
D680
```

But am getting output as

```
Processing file 0
Processing file 1
Processing file 2
Processing file 3
Processing file 4
Processing file 5
Processing file 6
```

could anyone pls help me to print values in the array

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected output,

- we don't require "Processing file" in that `echo` command.
- we don't need to pass the index value of array while looping it in `for` loop.

Try as

```
declare -a files=( "A1S0" "D1S0" "D2S0" "D3S0" "D4S0" "D5S0" "D6S0" )
command_to_get_filesizes() 
{
  for i in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
  done
}
command_to_get_filesizes
```

Comment: The ! is not the "not" operator in this context. It makes the expression expand into the indexes of the array, instead of the values. Necessary for associative arrays, but also useful for numeric indices (which can be sparse but are still processed in numeric order).

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'index' is undefined. What you intended was

```
echo Processing file "${files[i]}"
```

What the original does is obscure. All variables are (potentially) arrays with a zeroth element. (Try `echo "${PATH[$junk]}"`.) So that whole construct `"${i[${index}]}"` resolves as `${i[0]}`, which just echoes `$i`.

Your title is slightly misleading: you do not pass the array into the function (as a parameter): it is merely a global array variable.

@Siva is correct in that you can iterate over the array values simply. However, if you need both the index and the value in the same iteration, this does it for me.

```
for n in "${!N[@]}"; do
    printf '%8d  %s\n' "${n}" "${N[n]}"
done
```

Comment: What do you mean by *`"${1[${i}]}"` works*? I get a `bad substitution` error in bash 5.0.16

Comment: Note that you can also do `${files[i]}` which saves the double translation between integer and number.

Comment: Yes, the index part of an indexed array element notation is an arithmetic expression, and the `$` is not required for shell variables in an arithmetic expression: `"${N[n]}"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Had I not tested this, I would not have had the opportunity to be astonished. But it has vanished from my history, and I can't reconstruct what I thought I did. So conceded and edited. I did run across this construct which lets you alter global arrays by variable name from within functions: declare -g "$1[4]=abc";